# Execute server python script on angularJS/python and flask website

Tags: python, angularjs

I'm the new developer of a project and I'm looking to understand how it works. The web site uses AngularJS and Python with the Flask framework.

My files : /controllers/quotes.py : controller python for my quotes /static/controller.js : my local controller /static/service.js : my local factory /app.js : routes container

What I have understood about angularJS: controller.js calls service.js which calls quotes.py through app.js. Or am I wrong?

What's important on my files (new function) : /controller/quotes.py :

```
@quotes.route('/quotes/announce/<int:announce_id>/quote/<int:quote_id>/pdf', methods=['POST'])
def pdf(quote_id):
  return jsonify(result=True)
```

It's just a simple code to try the loading.

My file /static/quotes/controller.js

```
$scope.downloadQuote = function() {

  QuoteService.downloadQuote($routeParams.announceId, $routeParams.quoteId)
  .then(function(data, status) {
    alert("1");
  })
  .catch(function(data, status) {
    alert("2");
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.errorMessage = "Erreur, impossible de charger le pdf";
  });
};
```

My file /static/quotes/service.js :

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('QuoteService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$http', function ($q, $timeout, $http) {

return ({
  downloadQuote : downloadQuote
});

function downloadQuote(announceId, quoteId) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.post('/quotes/announce/' + announceId + '/quote/' + quoteId + '/pdf', {quoteId:data.quoteId})
  .success(function (data, status) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  })
  .error(function (data) {
    deferred.reject();
  });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

My part of file app.js :

```
.when('/app/quotes/announce/:announceId/quote/:quoteId/pdf' {
  controller: 'quoteController',
  access: {restricted: true}
  template: '',
})
```

When I do python manage.py runserver, if I apply the .when in the app.js, all of the web site is blank (like a white screen on every pages). If I do not apply the .when, I have a 404 in terminal when the request POST on that page. Wht's the problem ?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Blank web site when I use new route on app.js, pointing to my python function. But I don't understand, why ?